# send id to another php file using JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i write below code for sending id to another php file

```
function selectCheckBox(k) {
    answer = confirm("Do you really want check?");
    if(answer == true) {
        var e = document.Check.elements.length;
        var cnt = 0;
        total = document.Check.elements[k].value;
        PostVar = "id=" + total;
        alert(PostVar);
        makePostRequest("check.php", PostVar);
    }
}
```

in this code i got PostVar value as id=121

in check.php code is as shown

```
require 'dbconnect.php';
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query="update members set status_admin='Yes' where userid='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

but results in the mysql table are not updated

please guide me

Comment: Is the id being passed in sql query ?

Comment: what exactly does `makePostRequest()` do?

Comment: `die($_REQUEST['id']);` returns what?  If nothing, it's more than likely in the makePostRequest function which we can't help with because you didn't include it....  all relevant code DOES help..

Comment: Careful the SQL injection! use `$id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);` instead

Comment: @Blaster:i cant predict whether the request is send to check.php or not

Comment: Also, on a side note.. get away from using mysql_ extensions in PHP... instead use PDO or Mysqli...  the mysql extentions are deprecated.

Comment: You also can't give all the necessary information for us to help you....  Quality question, leads to Quality Answers....

Comment: @Justin: Could you give me a reference for that? It might be something very interesting to know with the work environment I have.

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few Suggestions For Debugging**

- Check the output of `$_REQUEST` using `print_r($_REQUEST)`
- Or See output of your query using `exit($query)`
- See if mysql returns any error `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())`

And put this on top of your script to see any other errors from current page or included pages:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply do makeGetRequest("check.php?id="+total); and get rid of the PostVar thing in some way? Your $_REQUEST will catch it nicely.

Also, careful the SQL injection! use `$id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);` instead.